# How to send document with Telegram Bot in Java

Tags: java, mime-types, multipartform-data, telegram, telegram-bot

I have telegram bot and it works fine but can handle only text. I want to improve it to process files. I have already check api and did some search in *multipart/form-data* examples in java. Unfortunately still not clear for me. Is there any simple library or smth that may help me ?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api

Comment: ok, I'll try to check it and update question in case of success